# Display records using cte in sql

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I have table as follows:

```
Date                      Name              TypeID
---------------------------------------------------
01/01/2012 01:50          abc                 70
01/01/2012 02:20          bcd                 101
01/01/2012 01:30          abc                 70
01/01/2012 01:55          bcd                 101   
01/01/2012 02:15          abc                 70
01/01/2012 02:15          xyz                 110
```

Now from this table i want following result.

```
Date                      Name              TypeID
---------------------------------------------------
01/01/2012 01:30          abc                 70
01/01/2012 01:55          bcd                 101 
01/01/2012 02:15          xyz                 110    
01/01/2012 01:50          abc                 70
01/01/2012 02:15          abc                 70    
01/01/2012 02:20          bcd                 101
```

i want records like this. means i want records in sorting order with latest one but first it should display laste records for all the typeid and then rest of the records in sorting.

can anyone help me to solve this problem using CTE or other query in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state the DBMS you are using, but as you mention CTE, you should also have window functions available:

```
select date, name, typeId
from (
  select date, -- btw: an awful name for a column 
         name, -- another awful name for a column
         typeId,
         dense_rank() over (partition by name order by date) as rnk
  from the_table
) t
order by rnk, name;
```